# Different result using mysql LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-like

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
  INNER JOIN first_name USING first_name_id
  INNER JOIN last_name USING last_name_id
WHERE CONCAT (
    REPLACE(first_name, " ", ""),
    REPLACE(last_name, " ", ""))
LIKE "%John Smith%"
```

There is no result using this query however when I use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
  INNER JOIN first_name USING first_name_id
  INNER JOIN last_name USING last_name_id
  AND fn.first_name LIKE "%John%"
  AND last_name LIKE "%Smith%"`
```

I have to use `John Smith` and remove the spaces between the names. The expected return values for mysql query is: `%JohnSmith%`

What is the proper way to show the result?

Comment: For your first query after CONCAT the value will be `JohnSmith` which isn't like `%John Smith%` because there is a space in the middle

Comment: Ah. Right. I see your point. and it returned the result.

Comment: If its not a problem to use space in Where clause, you can try this,
WHERE CONCAT(REPLACE(first_name, " ", ""),' ', REPLACE(last_name, " ", "")) LIKE "%John Smith%";

Answer (score 0):

use the function

```
TRIM(COLUMN_NAME);
```

to remove the whitespace

eg:    TRIM(FIRST_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the fact that you are concatenating the first and last name and also matching it with different keyword. You can choose any of the below queries to do whatever you were trying to do in the first place.

In this one i have simply removed space from your like keyword.

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
  INNER JOIN first_name USING first_name_id
  INNER JOIN last_name USING last_name_id
WHERE CONCAT(REPLACE(first_name, " ", ""), REPLACE(last_name, " ", "")) LIKE "%JohnSmith%"
```

**Or**

In this one i have introduced a space in concat function between first and last name columns.

```
SELECT * 
FROM results
  INNER JOIN first_name USING first_name_id
  INNER JOIN last_name USING last_name_id
WHERE CONCAT(REPLACE(first_name, " ", ""), " ", REPLACE(last_name, " ", "")) LIKE "%John Smith%"
```